# How to change all values to the first in the sequence?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 3 columns: UserID, Channel, and Order_Sequence. I want the Channel column to keep the first channel based on the first sequence of the user id. How can I get it to output the column WANT in sql?

[image]

---

Comment: Are you using any particular SQL "flavor" (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, etc.)?

Comment: @PM77-1 don't believe so - Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64)   Jun 15 2019 00:26:19   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Hint: you will need a correlated subquery in SELECT clause.

Comment: So it's "SQL Server" flavor.  Actually you can solve it with just standard SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `first_value()`:

```
select t.*,
       first_value(channel) over (partition by userid order by sequence) as want
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the good old `correlated subquery` approach

```
select t.*, (select channel from test where userid=t.userid and order_sequence=1) as want
from test t;
```